# CALayer still displaying after call to removeFromSuperlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am having a bit of an issue synchronizing a set of function calls. What I am trying to achieve is

1. Display my first view and allow it to capture mouse cordinates
2. Remove my first view then capture a screen shot with CGWindowListCreateImage based on the mouse coordinates from step one.
3. Display my second view.

Everything works as it should except the first view is not removed during the screenshot. I am not sure what is causing the issue. The first view does have some basic core animation. And I have overridden the drawRect method to apply some custom animations. I have tried running the code inside of the following thinking that the issue may be caused by the runloop not being able to remove the view prior to the screenshot.

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

}];
```

Here is my entire function for handling the transition. When running it in the debugger and setting a breakpoint at the beginning of the function and stepping over it line by line the first view is always removed during the screen capture. Hence why I feel it is a sync issue causing my problem.

```
- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent{

    //Get point based on screen cordiates not releative to any window or view.
    _endPoint = [NSEvent mouseLocation];

    //Remove the shape layer from screen
    [self.shapeLayer removeAllAnimations];
    [self.shapeLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
     self.shapeLayer = nil;

    //Grab a pointer to the window so we can add the View 2
    NSWindow * win = self.view.window;

    //Order the window out so that we can capture the screen without capturing our transparent view
    //[win orderOut:nil];
    //set the current view to hidden so that it does not conflic with the screen capture
    //[self.view setHidden:YES];

     //proceed to remove it fromt the superview as we nolonger need it
     [self.view removeFromSuperview];



    //Get the rect of the main screen so we can calculate our capture rectangle
    NSRect screenRect =  [[NSScreen mainScreen]frame];

    //Capture rect

    _squareRect = CGMakeRect(blah,balh,blah,blah);

    //Capture the screen with the specified rectangle
    NSImage * image = [self captureScreen:_squareRect];
    [self addToPastBoard:image];

    //Create the Edit view and inject the image
    EditControlsViewController *editViewController = [[EditControlsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"EditControlsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] image:image];

    //Set the frame and bounds of the edit view
    [editViewController.view setFrame:self.view.window.frame];
    [editViewController.view setBounds:self.view.window.frame];
    editViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [editViewController.imgView setImage:image];

    //Since our image has been captured order the window back to front;
    //[win orderFront:nil];

    //Replace the current view with the new view. Since we previously removed our view just add the new
    //view as a subview of the content view
    [win.contentView addSubview:editViewController.view positioned:NSWindowAbove relativeTo:nil];

    NSView * editView = editViewController.view;


    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(editView);
    [win.contentView addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[editView]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:views]];

    [win.contentView addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[editView]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:views]];

    //beautiful way to help debug constraints;
    //[win visualizeConstraints:[win.contentView constraints]];


}
```

Is removeFromSuperLayer an async call?

Is their something I can do to allow the view to finish its removal?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All updates to the screen take place asynchronously. You make changes to the state of the screen, and then on the next pass through the event loop, your changes are rendered to the screen. In your code, you apply changes, then capture the CURRENT state of the screen, before your changes take place.

Take the code that captures the screen-shot, put it in a separate method, and then call it using `[self performSelect: @selector(screenshot) witObject: nil afterDelay: 0]`. That call queues up your selector to be called at the END of the next pass through the event loop, after your screen changes have been applied.

You could also use

```
dispatch_after(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
  {
     //Code to execute after servicing the event loop
  }
);
```

I have a category on NSObject that implements a method performBlockOnMainQueue:afterDelay: that uses code very similar to the above dispatch_after call. Since it uses blocks, the code you want to invoke after a delay is in-line, and has access to variables in the enclosing scope.

EDIT: You can find the NSObject+performBlockAfterDelay category in my [**"RandomBlobs" project on github**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/RandomBlobs)

Comment: Thank you very very much for your time!!!! I would love that category if you would not mind sharing. This was indeed the issue. For some reason [self performSelect: @selector(screenshot) witObject: nil afterDelay: 0] was the only one that worked. I simply needed to change the delay to 0.1 instead of 0.

Comment: I just edited my answer and added a link to a project that includes the category.